# Does anyone know how to get the Font Awesome Pro License to work with Squarespace?

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to the light version of Font Awesome - it only works with the Pro License which I own. I added the site's URL to the Font Awesome CDN. The free version works great, but when I try to use the Pro version, Squarespace blocks it. Or Chrome blocks it - I am not sure. Ideas?

The alert I see in Chrome Inspector is:

> config-vendors-1380f31f25f8941023e5-min.en-US.js:1 Cross-Origin Read  Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  https://events.squarespace.com/api/v1/events with MIME type  application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.